# Updating many different users in dreamweaver and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i have one user table with columns : userid, username, password, email, agree_1, comment_1, agree_2, comment_2, ...........BELOW IS THE CODE GENERATED BY DREAMWEAVER, IT WILL RESTRICT ACCESS TO PAGES, YOU CAN ONLY HAVE ACCESS WHEN YOU ARE LOGGED IN. ALSO IT UPDATES THE USERS TABLE WITH THE RECORD SET QUERY BEING CREATED BY DREAMWEAVER

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

 // *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
 // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
 $isValid = False; 

// When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username setequal to their username. 
// Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
if (!empty($UserName)) { 
// Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an   ID established when they login. 
// Parse the strings into arrays. 
$arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
$arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
// Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
} 
return $isValid; 
}

 $MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
 if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
 $MM_qsChar = "?";
 $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
 if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
 $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" .   urlencode($MM_referrer);
 header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
 exit;
 }
 ?>
 <?php
 if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
 function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?  mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

 switch ($theType) {
 case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
 case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
 return $theValue;
 }
 }

 $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
 $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
 }

 if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
 $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE users SET Agree_50=%s, comment_50=%s, Agree_51=%s,    comment_51=%s, Agree_52=%s, comment_52=%s, Agree_53=%s, comment_53=%s, Agree_54=%s, comment_54=%s, Agree_55=%s, comment_55=%s, Agree_56=%s, comment_56=%s, Agree_57=%s, comment_57=%s, Agree_58=%s, comment_58=%s, Agree_59=%s, comment_59=%s, Agree_60=%s, comment_60=%s, Agree_61=%s, comment_61=%s, Agree_62=%s, comment_62=%s, Agree_63=%s, comment_63=%s, Agree_64=%s, comment_64=%s, Agree_65=%s, comment_65=%s, Agree_66=%s, comment_66=%s, Agree_67=%s, comment_67=%s, Agree_68=%s, comment_68=%s, Agree_69=%s, comment_69=%s, Agree_70=%s, comment_70=%s, Agree_71=%s, comment_71=%s, Agree_72=%s, comment_72=%s, Agree_73=%s, comment_73=%s, Agree_74=%s, comment_74=%s, Agree_75=%s, comment_75=%s, Agree_76=%s, comment_76=%s, Agree_77=%s, comment_77=%s, Agree_78a=%s, comment_78a=%s, Agree_79a=%s, comment_79a=%s, Agree_78b=%s, comment_78b=%s, Agree_79b=%s, comment_79b=%s, Agree_80=%s, comment_80=%s, Agree_81=%s, comment_81=%s, Agree_82=%s, comment_82=%s, Agree_83=%s, comment_83=%s, Agree_84=%s, comment_84=%s, Agree_85=%s, comment_85=%s, Agree_86=%s, comment_86=%s, Agree_87=%s, comment_87=%s, Agree_88=%s, comment_88=%s, Agree_89=%s, comment_89=%s, Agree_90=%s, comment_90=%s, Agree_91=%s, comment_91=%s, Agree_92=%s, comment_92=%s, Agree_93=%s, comment_93=%s, Agree_94=%s, comment_94=%s, Agree_95=%s, comment_95=%s, Agree_96=%s, comment_96=%s, Agree_97=%s, comment_97=%s, Agree_98=%s, comment_98=%s, Agree_99=%s, comment_99=%s, Agree_100=%s, comment_100=%s WHERE id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_50'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_50'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_51'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_51'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_52'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_52'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_53'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_53'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_54'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_54'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_55'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_55'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_56'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_56'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_57'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_57'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_58'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_58'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_59'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_59'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_60'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_60'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_61'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_61'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_62'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_62'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_63'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_63'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_64'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_64'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_65'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_65'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_66'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_66'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_67'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_67'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_68'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_68'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_69'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_69'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_70'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_70'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_71'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_71'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_72'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_72'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_73'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_73'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_74'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_74'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_75'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_75'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_76'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_76'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_77'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_77'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_78a'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_78a'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_79a'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_79a'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_78b'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_78b'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_79b'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_79b'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_80'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_80'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_81'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_81'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_82'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_82'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_83'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_83'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_84'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_84'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_85'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_85'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_86'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_86'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_87'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_87'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_88'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_88'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_89'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_89'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_90'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_90'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_91'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_91'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_92'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_92'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_93'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_93'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_94'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_94'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_95'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_95'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_96'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_96'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_97'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_97'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_98'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_98'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_99'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_99'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_100'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_100'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id1'], "int"));

      mysql_select_db($database_NAWFIA_1, $NAWFIA_1);
     $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $NAWFIA_1) or die(mysql_error());

    $updateGoTo = "draft_chapter3_success.php";
   if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
   $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
   $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
   }
   header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
  }

  mysql_select_db($database_NAWFIA_1, $NAWFIA_1);
 $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT id, Agree_50, comment_50, Agree_51, comment_51, Agree_52, comment_52, Agree_53, comment_53, Agree_54, comment_54, Agree_55, comment_55, Agree_56, comment_56, Agree_57, comment_57, Agree_58, comment_58, Agree_59, comment_59, Agree_60, comment_60, Agree_61, comment_61, Agree_62, comment_62, Agree_63, comment_63, Agree_64, comment_64, Agree_65, comment_65, Agree_66, comment_66, Agree_67, comment_67, Agree_68, comment_68, Agree_69, comment_69, Agree_70, comment_70, Agree_71, comment_71, Agree_72, comment_72, Agree_73, comment_73, Agree_74, comment_74, Agree_75, comment_75, Agree_76, comment_76, Agree_77, comment_77, Agree_78a, comment_78a, Agree_79a, comment_79a, Agree_78b, comment_78b, Agree_79b, comment_79b, Agree_80, comment_80, Agree_81, comment_81, Agree_82, comment_82, Agree_83, comment_83, Agree_84, comment_84, Agree_85, comment_85, Agree_86, comment_86, Agree_87, comment_87, Agree_88, comment_88, Agree_89, comment_89, Agree_90, comment_90, Agree_91, comment_91, Agree_92, comment_92, Agree_93, comment_93, Agree_94, comment_94, Agree_95, comment_95, Agree_96, comment_96, Agree_97, comment_97, Agree_98, comment_98, Agree_99, comment_99, Agree_100, comment_100 FROM users WHERE users.id";
 $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $NAWFIA_1) or die(mysql_error());
  $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
  ?>
```

this works. when i login with user id of 1, the comments row of the table updates successfully, but when i logout and login with another user may be with id of 2 or 3, it will still UPDATE THE USER ID OF 1. PLEASE I NEED HELP ON HOW TO MAKE IT TO  UPDATE ROW OF ANY USER THAT LOGS IN.

Comment: Caps Lock is on. http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m92xxkspxh1qbze77o1_1280.jpg

Comment: My advise: throw away, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Can you show your HTML code?. It seems that value of the element with name **id1** doesn't change its value.

Comment: First mistake: "Letting" Dreamweaver write your code for you (`Explode`???). Second mistake: Trying to fix it without a clue. Third mistake: Not abandoning it and going with a reasonable, well-developed package that suits your needs. Looking at the `UPDATE` statement about midway, uhoohhooh, I'm woozy. `comment_65`? *`comment_99`* **??!?** What is going on here? What are you trying to make, maybe we can offer some suggestions to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to check or make sure if the posted value `$id1` corresponds to your userId.
2. `WHERE id=%s` id is integer, you could use `%d`.
3. Use of mysql_query is not recommended(it is deprecated, use PDO).

It is recommended to store user id in a session variable once user logs in , in such a way that

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $userId;
```

And use the same in the update query.